# How to add Navigation Arrow to rmarkdown ioslide?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I have searched this for almost a week and couldn't fin answers. Finally, I have created it myself, so I would like to share my example.

Step 0.
Add a css file into your markdown

```
      output:
        ioslides_presentation:
          css: foo.css
```

Step 1.
Find your preferred left right arrow png and save to your folder

Step 2.
Insert below javascript and html under each title

```
 <a href="javascript:slidedeck.prevSlide()">
      <img class="animated-navl" border="0" src="left.png" /></a>
      <a href="javascript:slidedeck.nextSlide()">
      <img class="animated-navr"border="0" src="right.png" /></a>
```

Step 3.under css file I have added this code to adjust the arrow size and position

```
      img.animated-navl{
        width: auto;
        height: 20px;
       position:absolute;
          bottom:0;
          right:25px;
      }
      img.animated-navr{
       width: auto;
        height: 20px;
       position:absolute;
          bottom:0;
          right:0;
      }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: Instead of answering in the question box, please write down your question there and tick the box "Answer your own question". Then you can give your answer.

Comment: I am voting to keep open to give the OP a chance to correct this.